# laravel join with average of a column in another table

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a Food model and Review model. in my reviews table in database I have two columns : `food_id` and `rate`. Each user can rate foods and rate is an integer number between 1~5.

I need to get all records in foods table and average of rate column in reviews where food_id is the id of each food.

```
$foods = Food::join('reviews', 'foods.id', '=', 'reviews.food_id')->select(
            'foods.*',
            'AVERAGE(reviews.rate) WHERE reviews.food_id = foods.id AS food_rate'
)->get();
```

And of course this code will raise `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error`

How can I join with average of a column in another table?

```
SELECT  foods.*, AVG(reviews.rate) AS food_rate
    FROM foods
        LEFT OUTER JOIN reviews
            ON reviews.food_id = foods.id
    GROUP BY foods.id
```

in fact this MYSQL code needs to be written with Laravel

Comment: use `\DB::raw('AVERAGE(reviews.rate) as avg_rate')->where('reviews....`

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression::where() @FelippeDuarte

Comment: read the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions

Answer (score 1):

```
$foods = Food::select(
            '*',
            \DB::raw('AVG(reviews.rate) AS food_rate'),
        )->leftJoin('reviews', 'foods.id', '=', 'reviews.food_id')->groupBy('foods.id');
```

and we need to set `'strict' => false` in `config/database.php`